# How can I install a python package to google Colab from a private Pypi repository?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, jupyter, google-colaboratory, pypi

My company has developed python packages and hosted them on a private Pypi repository. I wish to install these packages on a Google Colab notebook.

If they were on a public Pypi repository this would work:

```
!pip3 install --index-url=https://pypi.spotify.net/spotify/production confidence
```

however, it causes this error:

```
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.spotify.net/spotify/production
Collecting confidence
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f0f9e601748>, 'Connection to pypi.spotify.net timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /spotify/production/confidence/
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f0f9e601588>, 'Connection to pypi.spotify.net timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /spotify/production/confidence/
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f0f9e6015f8>, 'Connection to pypi.spotify.net timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /spotify/production/confidence/
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f0f9e601390>, 'Connection to pypi.spotify.net timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /spotify/production/confidence/
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f0f9e6012e8>, 'Connection to pypi.spotify.net timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /spotify/production/confidence/
  ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement confidence (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for confidence
```

I suspect this is due to google Colab being a hosted notebook. This means that it is not connecting to Pypi via my work wifi, but from a google server.

Comment: This feels relevant: https://techsupportallbugs.wordpress.com/2018/06/05/using-git-with-colab-via-ssh/

Comment: Is there any chance that repo is behind a proxy? If so, how could you setup proxy settings in the system that hosts the notebook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to either:

- make the package repository available to the public internet (unlikely that you'll actually want to do this)
- connect Colaboratory to a local runtime: https://research.google.com/colaboratory/local-runtimes.html